# Show an array in format of scientific notation

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to show my results in scientific notation (e.g., 1.2e3). My data is in array format. Is there a function like `tolist()` that can convert the array to float so I can use %E to format the output?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.zeros(shape=(5,5), dtype=float)
b=a.tolist()
print a, type(a), b, type(b)
print '''%s''' % b 
# what I want is 
print '''%E''' % function_to_float(a or b)
```

Answer (score 14):

If your version of Numpy is 1.7 or greater, you should be able to use the `formatter` option to [`numpy.set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html#numpy.set_printoptions).  <strike>1.6 should definitely work -- 1.5.1 may work as well.</strike>

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(shape=(5, 5), dtype=float)
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': lambda x: format(x, '6.3E')})
print a
```

Alternatively, if you don't have `formatter`, you can create a new array whose values are formatted strings in the format you want.  This will create an entirely new array as big as your original array, so it's not the most memory-efficient way of doing this, but it may work if you can't upgrade numpy.  (I tested this and it works on numpy 1.3.0.)

To use this strategy to get something similar to above:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(shape=(5, 5), dtype=float)
formatting_function = np.vectorize(lambda f: format(f, '6.3E'))
print formatting_function(a)
```

`'6.3E'` is the format you want each value printed as.  You can consult the [this documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec) for more options.

In this case, `6` is the minimum width of the printed number and `3` is the number of digits displayed after the decimal point.

Comment: My Numpy version is 1.6.2, but why my set_printoptions does not have the keyword 'formatter' I know this is dumb....

Comment: @tao.hong Hmmm -- the code got committed to numpy before 1.6 was created, but it looks like it didn't make in until 1.7.  I've added an alternate (less efficient) method above if you can't upgrade Numpy.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I think if a is an array, it will not work. But if it is a list, it works.

Comment: Hmmm.  I did use `numpy` intead of `np` in the second example, but I can paste that code into a python terminal and it just works for me.  How does it not work for your array?

Comment: It did not change the expression into the scientific way in my case. Here is the results. '[['1.00' '1.00' '1.00' '1.00' '1.00']
 ['1.00' '1.00' '1.00' '1.00' '1.00']
 ['1.00' '1.00' '1.00' '1.00' '1.00']
 ['1.00' '1.00' '1.00' '1.00' '1.00']
 ['1.00' '1.00' '1.00' '1.00' '1.00']]'

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  If I try to apply `formatting_function` to an array of ones, I get `'1.000E+0'`.

Answer (score 3):

You can format each of the *elements* of an array in scientific notation and then display them as you'd like. Lists cannot be converted to floats, they have floats inside them potentially.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeroes(shape=(5, 5), dtype=float)
for e in a.flat:
    print "%E" % e
```

or

```
print ["%E" % e for e in a.flat]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Does that mean you change this 5 by 5 matrix to a vector with 25 elements? Is there a way to keep the shape of matrix and also convert it to float type?

Comment: Edit: It's 'np.zeros', not 'np.zeroes'.

Comment: this returns results as strings?