# How can I display numbers in scientific form inside a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scientific-notation

I know the Python code for displaying numbers in scientific form is:

```
print("Number is {:.2e}".format(Number))
```

How would I do the same for a (numpy) matrix? I've tried the same format for a 2 by 2 matrix and receive the error message: "TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.**format**"

Is there a quick and easy way of displaying all the numbers inside the matrix in scientific form at once?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677833/show-an-array-in-format-of-scientific-notation) post should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the exact code that allows you to do this:

```
j = 0
for j, i in TheMatrix.flat:
    j += 1
    print("The Matrix Value {} is {:.2e}".format(j, i))
```